# update the secondary or conrast color in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

**strong text**[image: **screen shot of material stepper**]

I', using angular material stepper  and in style.scss blue as primary color
but by default I'm getting the gray color as secondary or contrast I'm not sure
I want it to update to  #a49304
how can I achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following **css**:

```
$primaryColor: blue;
$secondaryColor: #a49304;

.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon { background-color: $secondaryColor; }
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected { background-color: $primaryColor; }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jogcrw?file=src/styles.scss)